# How to import third-party module to Sublime Text 3 (Mac)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, import, sublimetext3

Python newbie here. I'm trying to import the tabulate (https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) module for my project. I have installed it using pip3 using Terminal. When I try to run my program using IDLE (3.9.1), it works perfectly; however, when I use Sublime Text 3, it fails to import the tabulate module. How can I make Sublime Text 3 capable of reading the module? It keeps telling me: '''
ImportError: No module named tabulate'''

Comment: Hello, I didn't use sublime for python a lot but i found this [link](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion). Try it. Otherwise i suggest you switch to PyCharm or Visual Studio Code

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks @Dad! I decided to look at PyCharm instead of Sublime.